Prove $f = 0$ Almost Everywhere in $L^1$ Under Given Conditions
Problem:
Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose there exists a countable set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$
\int_p^q f(x) \, dx = 0 \quad \text{for all } p, q \notin S.
$$
Goal:
Prove that $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere (a.e.).

My Approach:

Define $F(q) = \int_p^q f(x) \, dx$. The given hypothesis implies $F(q) = 0$ for all $q \notin S$.

Since $S$ is countable, $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and $F(q)$ is continuous on this dense set.
I concluded that $F(q) = 0$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$, which implies $\int_p^q f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$.


I then decomposed $f$ into the sets where $f > 0$ and $f < 0$:

Define $A = \{x : f(x) > 0\}$ and $B = \{x : f(x) < 0\}$, and approximate these sets using intervals $\{I_i\}$.
I constructed $f_n = f \chi_{A_n}$, where $A_n$ is the union of $I_i$ up to $n$, and similarly for $B_n$.


Using the Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT), I showed:

$\int f \chi_A \, dx = 0$,
$\int f \chi_B \, dx = 0$,
which implies $A$ and $B$ have measure zero.


Since $A$ and $B$ (where $f > 0$ or $f < 0$) have measure zero, $f = 0$ a.e.



My Question:

Is my reasoning correct that $\int_p^q f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \, dx = 0$?
Does this approach rigorously prove $f(x) = 0$ a.e., or are there any gaps in my argument?

Any feedback or alternative approaches would be appreciated!


How do you go from being continuous and zero on a dense subset to being zero on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Using the idea that a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ (or more generally, any topological space) that is zero on a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ must be identically zero on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

But $F$ isn’t continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, it is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$. I don’t think that allows you to make conclusions about its behavior on $S$

what about using Luzin's theorem, and now working with a new  function h(x) continuous and we can show its integral over $\mathbb{R} \setminus S$ is 0.

One idea thats a bit more explicit is to write $A=\bigcup_{n}\{x: f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$.
Denote
$A_{n}=\{x: f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$, you can cover $A_{n}$ by a countable collection of intervals of the form $[p,q]$ for $p,q\in S^{c}$ (why?), then use that to conclude that $\mu_{L}(A_{n})=0$ for every $n$. Similar argument holds for $B$.
In fact you can weaken your claim to any $S$ where $S^{c}$ has enough points to cover $\Bbb{R}$ by intervals with endpoints in $S^{c}$.

So, I approached it this way. Using $\int_p^q f(x) , dx = 0$ for $p, q \notin S$, define $A_n = {x : f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}}$. Since $S^c$ is dense (as $S$ is countable), $A_n$ can be covered by intervals $[p, q]$ with $p, q \in S^c$. On $A_n$, $f(x) \geq \frac{1}{n}$ implies $\int_{[p, q] \cap A_n} f(x) , dx = 0$, so $\mu([p, q] \cap A_n) = 0$. Thus, $\mu(A_n) = 0$. Similarly, $\mu(B_n) = 0$ for $B_n = {x : f(x) \leq -\frac{1}{n}}$. Since $f(x) \neq 0$ only on $A = \cup A_n$ and $B = \cup B_n$, $\mu(A \cup B) = 0$, so $f(x) = 0$ a.e. Thank you for your hint.
